# ¿Cómo puedo firmar un archivo XML en PHP con un certificado .PFX?

Tags: php, xml

tengo un problema del cual necesito su ayuda, necesito firmar un archivo XML en PHP con un certificado tipo .PFX, ustedes sabrán de alguna librería open source o bien algún código que me pueda ayudar con el tema, de antemano muchas gracias

Saludos

Comment: Hola podrías utilizar Open SSL "http://php.net/manual/es/book.openssl.php"
Yo lo he utilizado para firmar un XML para facturación electrónica en México.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FredoAR pero te comento, que hay ciertos nodos que no se manejan con OpenSSL y no sé si es que no he buscado lo suficiente, pero para mi se queda corto a lo que necesito, ya que debo firmar sobre un nodo el XML y adicional obtener el Modulus y el Exponente lo cual no hace, he podido firmar TODO el XML sin problemas pero para la SAT acá en Guatemala no es válida la firma, ya que como te comenté es sobre un nodo en específico y no todo el documento.

Comment: Lograste resolver el inconveniente @edwin? Tengo exactamente el mismo problema, he tratado con SignedXml de .net, una librería de PHP e incluso desde openssl pero me da inconvenientes.

Comment: Fijate @MaxPinto que no, aún sigo con lo mismo, sé que se puede hacer con un JavaBridge, pero de forma nativa en PHP no he encontrado la solución, con el JavaBridge tengo algunos problemas también, por el tema de versiones ya que el soporte a esta librería está descontinuado, sigo investigando, al encontrar algo con gusto lo comparto para la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: @EdwinVasquez yo al final terminé utilizando un servicio web que el "certificador" proporcionó. Entre los indicios que conseguí: utilizan Ruby on Rails para el firmado, utilizan sha256, y hacen referencia a "xades" en el firmado.

Comment: Quién es tu certificador o GFace? Infile?

Comment: @EdwinVasquez es Infile, logré resolver el inconveniente. Utilicé Java y ya logré firmar de mi lado también.

Comment: @MaxPinto podrías por favor compartirme tu solución, disculpa la molestia, de antemano gracias

Comment: con gusto, estaré subiendo algo a GitHub en algún momento y compartiendo la solución, mientras tanto escribime a esquimax.9@gmail.com

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias @MaxPinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También tuve inconvenientes para el firmado de XML, sobre todo utilizando XADES, para la facturación electrónica de Guatemala.

En mi caso, opté por realizar una librería en JAVA, debido a la facilidad para aplicar SHA256 y XADES, y posteriormente utilizo dicha librería desde donde lo neceite. Te comparto la solución que encontré en mi caso:

[Repositorio](https://github.com/maxpinto/xadesfelgt)

En el repositorio, se tiene un archivo .jar, que se puede utilizar de la siguiente manera:

**Ejemplos**

**PHP**

```
<?php shell_exec("java -jar xadesfelgt.jar signxmlfile <keyPath> <keyPassword> <xmlInPath> <xmlOutPath> <refUriToSign>");
```

**Python**

```
import subprocess subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'xadesfelgt.jar', 'signxmlfile', '<keyPath>', '<keyPassword>','<xmlInPath>', '<xmlOutPath>', '<refUriToSign>'])
```

**NODE.JS**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child; child = exec('java -jar xadesfelgt.jar signxmlfile <keyPath> <keyPassword> <xmlInPath> <xmlOutPath> <refUriToSign>', function (error, stdout, stderr){ console.log('stdout: ' + stdout); console.log('stderr: ' + stderr); if(error !== null){ console.log('exec error: ' + error); } });
```

En resumen, para el funcionamiento es necesario tener instalado JAVA, para le ejecución de archivos .jar. Funciona con el JDK de Java 1.7+.

Comment: Excelente Max, me es de mucha ayuda, también felicidades por esta colaboración, saludos compañero

Comment: Tu repositorio dejo de existir y tu respuesta dejo de ser valida.

Comment: repositorio ya no existe